# How to pass string from android render page to PCL page?

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

How to pass string value to android render page to PCL page.

I want to send token of **eventArgs.Account.Properties["access_token"]** to PCL page.

how can i do ?Please help.

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(LoginPage), typeof(LoginRender))]
namespace TestApp.Droid.Renderers
{
    public class LoginRender : PageRenderer
    {
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Page> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            // this is a ViewGroup - so should be able to load an AXML file and FindView<>
            var activity = this.Context as Activity;

            var auth = new OAuth2Authenticator(
                clientId: "", // your OAuth2 client id
                scope: "user_about_me", // the scopes for the particular API you're accessing, delimited by "+" symbols
                authorizeUrl: new Uri("https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth"), // the auth URL for the service
                redirectUrl: new Uri("https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html")); // the redirect URL for the service

            auth.Completed += (sender, eventArgs) => {
                if (eventArgs.IsAuthenticated)
                {
                    Toast.MakeText(this.Context, eventArgs.Account.Properties["access_token"], ToastLength.Long).Show();

                    App.SuccessfulLoginAction.Invoke();

                    App.SaveToken(eventArgs.Account.Properties["access_token"]);

                }
                else
                {
                    // The user cancelled
                }
            };

            activity.StartActivity(auth.GetUI(activity));
        }
    }
}
```

**App.cs**

```
public class App
    {
        static NavigationPage _NavPage;

        public static Page GetMainPage()
        {
            var profilePage = new ProfilePage();

            _NavPage = new NavigationPage(profilePage);

            return _NavPage;
        }

        public static bool IsLoggedIn
        {
            get { return !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_Token); }
        }

        static string _Token;
        public static string Token
        {
            get { return _Token; }
        }

        public static void SaveToken(string token)
        {
            _Token = token;
        }

        public static Action SuccessfulLoginAction
        {
            get
            {
                return new Action(() => {
                    _NavPage.Navigation.PopModalAsync();
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

above is my App.cs file code. static method can't return token.

**ProfilePage.cs in PCL**

```
public class ProfilePage : BaseContentPage
{
    public ProfilePage()
    {
        string tk = App.Token;

        var lbltoken = new Label()
        {
            FontSize = 20,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
            Text = tk,
        };
        var stack = new StackLayout
        {
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.StartAndExpand,
            Children = { lbltoken },
        };
        Content = stack;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm presuming that you have followed this example here: [How to login to facebook in Xamarin.Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24105390/how-to-login-to-facebook-in-xamarin-forms/24423833#24423833)

In that case you can use it in your PCL by calling `App.Token`

If that isn't working create a static property of the field you are using by calling `App.SaveToken(eventArgs.Account.Properties["access_token"]);`

With the edits you have made it is apparent that you set the value of your `Label` before the `App.Token` has a value.

A quick fix here could be to hook in to the `Page.Appearing` event, like so;

```
public class ProfilePage : BaseContentPage
{
    private Label _lbltoken;

    public ProfilePage()
    {
        Appearing += (object s, EventArgs a) => {
           _lbltoken.Text = App.Token;
        };

        string tk = App.Token;

        _lbltoken = new Label()
        {
            FontSize = 20,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
            Text = tk,
        };
        var stack = new StackLayout
        {
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.StartAndExpand,
            Children = { _lbltoken },
        };
        Content = stack;
    }
}
```

I've made your `Label` control a private variable so we can easily refer to it from elsewhere, and create a Event-handler for when your `ProfilePage` appears.
So every time you Page appears, it will set the value of `App.Token` in your `Label`.

This should work. However you would probably be better of checking out techniques like [MVVM](https://blog.verslu.is/xamarin/xamarin-forms-xamarin/beauty-and-the-beast-use-mvvm-to-unleash-inner-beauty/).

Comment: I know! Could you please show your `App` code? In the code you have posted you do `App.SaveToken(eventArgs.Account.Properties["access_token"]);` so you save the token value to a variable in your app class. Probably there is a static property in you `App` class as well, with which you can access the token in any page or any place in your application

Comment: Like I said, there is a static property Token in your App class. So when you have set the token, you can access it anywhere by `App.Token`

Comment: Exactly. you are right... but I can't show token in label. please see updated post for profilepage.cs file code.

Comment: That is because your `Page` is created before the `Token` is being filled. So you should create a mechanism to update the value in you UI when it is set.  I will update my answer.