# How to facebook login and get user's profile info in xamarin forms using xamarin.auth

Tags: facebook, xamarin.forms, xamarin.auth

I have developed one cross platform app using Xamarin forms. I am stuck on one facebook problem. So my question is how to get facebook user's profile info. I am just able to get "Id" and "Name" of user. However to get full details of user (i.e. email, profile picture, gender, birth date etc...)

[image]

Here is my code:

```
 protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Page> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        // this is a ViewGroup - so should be able to load an AXML file and FindView<>
        var activity = this.Context as Activity;

        var auth = new OAuth2Authenticator (
            clientId: App.Instance.OAuthSettings.ClientId, // your OAuth2 client id
            scope: App.Instance.OAuthSettings.Scope, // The scopes for the particular API you're accessing. The format for this will vary by API.
            authorizeUrl: new Uri (App.Instance.OAuthSettings.AuthorizeUrl), // the auth URL for the service
            redirectUrl: new Uri (App.Instance.OAuthSettings.RedirectUrl)); // the redirect URL for the service
        auth.AllowCancel = true;
        auth.Completed += LoginComplete;

        activity.StartActivity (auth.GetUI(activity));
    }
    public async void LoginComplete(object sender, AuthenticatorCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        // We presented the UI, so it's up to us to dismiss it.
       // DismissViewController(true, null);

        if (!e.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Not Authorised");
            return;
        }

        var accessToken = e.Account.Properties["access_token"].ToString();
        var expiresIn = Convert.ToDouble(e.Account.Properties["expires_in"]);
        var expiryDate = DateTime.Now + TimeSpan.FromSeconds(expiresIn);

        // Now that we're logged in, make a OAuth2 request to get the user's id.

        var request = new OAuth2Request("GET", new Uri("https://graph.facebook.com/me"), null, e.Account);
        var response = await request.GetResponseAsync();

        var obj = JObject.Parse(response.GetResponseText());

        var id = obj["id"].ToString().Replace("\"", ""); // Id has extraneous quotation marks

       // var user = await ParseFacebookUtils.LogInAsync(id, accessToken, expiryDate);
    }
```

Comment: Maybe this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24105390/how-to-login-to-facebook-in-xamarin-forms

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I got solution by adding fields in request URL.

```
var request = new OAuth2Request("GET", new Uri("https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=email,first_name,last_name,gender,picture"), null, e.Account);
```