# Xamarin.Forms PopModalAsync doesn't work

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, modal-dialog, xamarin.forms, xamarin.auth

I'm building an application using Xamarin.Forms and Xamarin.Auth to login with Facebook.

Here is what i'm doing:

App.cs:

```
public App()
{
    if (IsAuthenticated)
    {
        MainPage = new NavigationPage(new DetailPage());
    }
    else {
        MainPage = new NavigationPage(new WelcomePage());
    }
}

public Action SuccessfulLoginAction
{
    get
    {
        return new Action(() => MainPage.Navigation.PopModalAsync());
    }
}
```

WelcomePage:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace Project
{
    public class WelcomePage : ContentPage
    {
        public WelcomePage()
        {
            var login = new Button { Text = "Login" };
            login.Clicked += async (sender, e) =>
            {
                await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new LoginPage());
            };

            Content = new StackLayout
            {
                BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("F0C640"),
                Padding = new Thickness(10, 40, 10, 10),
                Children = {
                    new Label { Text = "Welcome", FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Large, typeof(Label)), HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center, TextColor = Color.White },
                    new Label { Text = "Please login", FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Medium, typeof(Label)), HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center, TextColor = Color.White },
                    login
                }
            };
        }
    }
}
```

LoginPage:

```
using Xamarin.Forms;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Project
{
    public class LoginPage : ContentPage
    {
    }
}
```

LoginRenderer:

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Auth;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Project;
using Project.iOS;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(LoginPage), typeof(LoginPageRenderer))]

namespace Project.iOS
{
    public class LoginPageRenderer : PageRenderer
    {
        bool IsShown;

        public override void ViewDidAppear(bool animated)
        {
            base.ViewDidAppear(animated);

            // Fixed the issue that on iOS 8, the modal wouldn't be popped.
            // url : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24105390/how-to-login-to-facebook-in-xamarin-forms
            if (!IsShown)
            {
                IsShown = true;

                var auth = new OAuth2Authenticator(
                    clientId: App.Instance.OAuthSettings.ClientId, // your OAuth2 client id
                    scope: App.Instance.OAuthSettings.Scope, // The scopes for the particular API you're accessing. The format for this will vary by API.
                    authorizeUrl: new Uri(App.Instance.OAuthSettings.AuthorizeUrl), // the auth URL for the service
                    redirectUrl: new Uri(App.Instance.OAuthSettings.RedirectUrl)); // the redirect URL for the service

                auth.Completed += (sender, eventArgs) =>
                {
                    // We presented the UI, so it's up to us to dimiss it on iOS.
                    DismissViewController (true, null);

                    if (eventArgs.IsAuthenticated)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Authenticated!!!!");
                        App.Instance.SaveToken(eventArgs.Account.Properties["access_token"]);
                        App.Instance.SuccessfulLoginAction.Invoke();
                    }
                    else {
                        Console.WriteLine("Not authenticated!!!!");
                        App.Instance.CanceledLoginAction.Invoke();
                    }
                };
                PresentViewController(auth.GetUI(), true, null);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Everything works pretty well, I can display the Modal page with the Facebook content and login. When the Authentication is done it goes through the auth.Completed event and call the App.Instance.SuccessfulLoginAction.Invoke(); but MainPage.Navigation.PopModalAsync() (in the App.cs) does not close the Modal page.

What i'm guessing is the Modal page is open in the Welcome Page and I try to close it in the App.cs file. Is it possible that it does not refer to the same object so I can't close it from here? How do you guys do to close your modal page when you create a platform specific renderer?

How can I do to close this Modal Page?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Although not quite elegant, here is how I handled authentication in my sample for authentication:

```
 public void HandleLoginSucceeded(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {   
        MainPage = new WelcomePage();
    }
```

Since `App.cs` is the entry point, I just reset the MainPage to point to a new location. I am not aware of the tradeoffs this might cause; however, I am aware that it works. You can see my sample on [Github](https://github.com/rlingineni/Xamarin.Forms_Authentication) to see my implementation.