# Xamarin - How to login using facebook APP

Tags: facebook, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I am using xamarin PCL project have two project android and IOS

I want to login through Facebook APP.
if Facebook app is already install in mobile then  application should use Facebook app credential

Please suggest me how to do this

Thanks in advance

Comment: is this what youre looking for : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24105390/how-to-login-to-facebook-in-xamarin-forms

Comment: this will open facebook login page in app and user have to add username and password. I want app should directly use facebook credential from facebook app

Comment: Take a look at this: https://components.xamarin.com/view/facebook-sdk

Comment: I search on facebook sdk but it did not help me. can you give me some material.