# Firebase Facebook Authentication with Xamarin Android

Tags: c#, android, firebase, xamarin, firebase-authentication

I have been trying to implement the logic found on the Firebase documentation on how to authenticate users through Facebook on Firebase. But i looks like it is more focused on `native android` and not  Xamarin. Could anyone help me out with a material? I have searched throughly online and forums for a sample.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24105390/how-to-login-to-facebook-in-xamarin-forms

Comment: @MartinDeSimone, Thanks for that but it has nothing to do with Firebase and i am not using forms. Besides, i have been able to implement login through facebook. I just want to add Firebase Auth to my app so i can see users who are logged in

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Could anyone help me out with a material? I have searched throughly online and forums for a sample.

I didn't find an official tutorial for Xamarin.Android, but I think you can still follow [Facebook Login for Android](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android) and [Authenticate Using Facebook Login on Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/facebook-login) to complement it in Xamarin.Android, basically they're pretty like.

First of all, install the Firebase sdks for Xamarin and together with the [Xamarin.Facebook.Android](https://github.com/xamarin/AndroidSupportComponents/).

Then follow the process in the tutorials above.

Here is my demo:

```
[Activity(Label = "LoginActivity", Exported = true)]
[IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionView },
DataScheme = "@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme"),]
public class LoginActivity : Activity, IFacebookCallback, IOnCompleteListener
{
    private ICallbackManager mCallbackManager;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        FacebookSdk.SdkInitialize(this.ApplicationContext);
        // Create your application here
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.loginlayout);

        FirebaseApp.InitializeApp(this);
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.Instance;

        LoginButton fblogin = FindViewById<LoginButton>(Resource.Id.fblogin);
        fblogin.SetReadPermissions("email", "public_profile");

        mCallbackManager = CallbackManagerFactory.Create();
        fblogin.RegisterCallback(mCallbackManager, this);
    }

    private void handleFacebookAccessToken(AccessToken accessToken)
    {
        AuthCredential credential = FacebookAuthProvider.GetCredential(accessToken.Token);
        mAuth.SignInWithCredential(credential).AddOnCompleteListener(this, this);
    }

    //facebook IFacebookCallback implementation
    public void OnSuccess(Java.Lang.Object p0)
    {
        LoginResult loginResult = p0 as LoginResult;
        handleFacebookAccessToken(loginResult.AccessToken);
    }

    public void OnCancel()
    {
    }

    public void OnError(FacebookException p0)
    {
    }

    //firebase IOnCompleteListener implementation
    public void OnComplete(Task task)
    {
        if (task.IsSuccessful)
        {
            FirebaseUser user = mAuth.CurrentUser;
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.MakeText(this, "Authentication failed.", ToastLength.Short).Show();
        }
    }

    // acitivity lifecycle
    protected override void OnStart()
    {
        base.OnStart();
        FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.CurrentUser;
    }

    protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, [GeneratedEnum] Result resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        var resultCodeNum = 0;
        switch (resultCode)
        {
            case Result.Ok:
                resultCodeNum = -1;
                break;

            case Result.Canceled:
                resultCodeNum = 0;
                break;

            case Result.FirstUser:
                resultCodeNum = 1;
                break;
        }
        mCallbackManager.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCodeNum, data);
    }
}
```

Layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
        android:id="@+id/fblogin"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<application android:label="AndroidFireBase">
  <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
      android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />
```