# firebase auth getting "Unsuccessful debug_token response from Facebook"

Tags: c#, firebase, facebook, xamarin, firebase-authentication

im trying to authenticate my app with Facebook and firebase authentication

i keep get this error no matter what i try:

```
Response: {
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "I>NVALID_IDP_RESPONSE : Unsuccessful debug_token response from Facebook: {\"error\":{\"message\":\"(#100) The App_id in the input_token did not match the Viewing App\",\"type\":\"OAuthException\",\"code\":100,\"fbtrace_id\":\"AGkb5UAzS66caoh8XplRXpB\"}}",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "INVALID_IDP_RESPONSE : Unsuccessful debug_token response from Facebook: {\"error\":{\"message\":\"(#100) The App_id in the input_token did not match the Viewing App\",\"type\":\"OAuthException\",\"code\":100,\"fbtrace_id\":\"AGkb5UAzS66caoh8XplRXpB\"}}",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "invalid"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

this is the facebook developer configuration:

[screen shot #1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BCj6T.png)

[screen shot #2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IylTK.png)

[screen shot #3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/04euM.png)

i also checked many times if the app ID and APP Secret is coppied correctly to firebase

i tried to reset the App secret code.. didn't help.

all the proccess to get the accessToken is working good because i can get the facebookprofile info

AuthService.cs

```
using Firebase.Auth;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace mada.Services
{
    public class AuthService
    {
        public FirebaseAuthLink CurrentAuth { get; set; }

        public async Task<FirebaseAuthLink> CreateEmailPasswordUser(string email, string password)
        {
            return await App.FirebaseService.AuthProviderInstance
                .CreateUserWithEmailAndPasswordAsync(email, password);
        }

        public async Task<FirebaseAuthLink> SignInWithEmailPassword(string email, string password)
        {
            return await App.FirebaseService.AuthProviderInstance
                .SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync(email, password);
        }

        public async Task SignInWithFacebook(string accessToken)
        {

            try
            {
                var auth = await App.FirebaseService.AuthProviderInstance.SignInWithOAuthAsync(FirebaseAuthType.Facebook, accessToken);
            } catch (FirebaseAuthException e)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
            };

        }

        public bool IsLoggedIn()
        {
            return CurrentAuth != null;
        }
    }
}
```

FirebaseService.cs

```
using Firebase.Auth;
using Firebase.Database;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace mada.Services
{
    public class FirebaseService
    {
        public readonly FirebaseAuthProvider AuthProviderInstance = new FirebaseAuthProvider(new FirebaseConfig("My firebase API key"));

        public readonly FirebaseClient FirebaseClientInstance = new FirebaseClient("my firebase url");
    }
}
```

FacebookLogin.cs

```
using Firebase.Auth;
using mada.Interfaces;
using mada.Models;
using mada.Services;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace mada.Views
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class FaceBookLogin : ContentPage
    {
        public static string accessToken = null;
        string ClientId = "My facebook app ID";
        public FaceBookLogin()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Indi.IsRunning = true;
            var apiRequest =
               "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id="
               + ClientId
               + "&display=popup&response_type=token&redirect_uri=https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html";

            var webView = new WebView
            {
                Source = apiRequest,
                HeightRequest = 1
            };

            webView.Navigated += WebViewOnNavigated;

            Content = webView;

        }

        private async void WebViewOnNavigated(object sender, WebNavigatedEventArgs e)
        {

            accessToken = ExtractAccessTokenFromUrl(e.Url);

            if (accessToken != "")
            {
                Indi.IsRunning = true;

                //var facebookProfile = await FacebookServices.GetFacebookProfileAsync(accessToken);
                //App.CurrentAccount = new Accounts { Key = facebookProfile.Id, PhotoUrl = facebookProfile.Picture.Data.Url, NickName = facebookProfile.Name, NewUser = true, UserType = "Facebook" };
                //await DBFire.saveAccount(App.CurrentAccount);

                await App.AuthService.SignInWithFacebook(accessToken);

                Indi.IsRunning = false;
                App.Current.MainPage = new MainScrolledPage();

            }
            else
            {
                App.Current.MainPage = new LoginPage();
                await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Didn't accessed to Facebook", "Please Try Again", "OK");
            }
        }

        public async Task GetFacebookProfileAsync(string accessToken)
        {
            var requestUrl = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.7/me/"
                + "?fields=name,picture,cover,age_range,devices,email,gender,is_verified"
                + "&access_token=" + accessToken;
            Indi.IsRunning = true;
            var httpClient = new HttpClient();

            var userJson = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(requestUrl);
            Indi.IsRunning = false;
        }

        private string ExtractAccessTokenFromUrl(string url)
        {
            if (url.Contains("access_token") && url.Contains("&expires_in="))
            {
                var at = url.Replace("https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html#access_token=", "");


                var accessToken = at.Remove(at.IndexOf("&expires_in="));

                return accessToken;
            }

            return string.Empty;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "App_id in the input_token did not match the Viewing App" you have a mismatch in ids

Comment: You could check the link below. It would be helpful. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44616248/firebase-facebook-authentication-with-xamarin-android

Comment: I don’t see where the debug token call is actually happening here - so I assume that is probably something your framework does in the background. My guess would be that it probably happens, when `await App.AuthService.SignInWithFacebook(accessToken);` gets called. But that doesn’t get the ClientId passed anywhere, so it probably reads it from some central configuration setting elsewhere?

Comment: i found my mistake.. i used the firebase api-key of my former project -_- thanks sushiHangover and every one for help!