# How to integrate SSO login in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, single-sign-on

Can you please help me to integrate Single-Sign-On login in Xamarin, Any one gives initiative Idea about it are highly appreciable.

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Could not install package 'Sunpoin.SSO.Plugin 1.0.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'MonoAndroid,Version=v7.0', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.           0

Answer (score 0):

I think `Sunpoin.SSO.Plugin` is a plugin for websites. You must use one that is compatible with `MonoAndroid` and if possible with PCL binaries.

I recommend you use [Xamarin.Auth](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Auth/) this component helps you to make an SSO in your Xamarin app.

Here's the best example in [StackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24105390/how-to-login-to-facebook-in-xamarin-forms/24423833#24423833) and a [tutorial](http://www.joesauve.com/using-xamarin-auth-with-xamarin-forms/) on it.

Good luck