# Xamarin Forms Native Facebook auth with UWP

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

This is referencing this question: [How to login to facebook in Xamarin.Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24105390/how-to-login-to-facebook-in-xamarin-forms).
I use a similar solution which uses Xamarin.Facebook.Android and Xamarin.Facebook.iOS for auth (https://github.com/mikeapple/XamarinFormsNativeFBLogin) and works perfectly, but I can't even begin to work out how to do native auth on UWP, there doesn't even seem to be Nuget to support this.

Does anyone have a workable solution to this problem that they would be prepared to share, or know of one that I could study, that would fit without having to repurpose my existing project too much?

Thanks

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wsdevsol/2015/02/12/integrating-facebook-authentication-in-universal-windows-apps/

Answer (score 1):

for this same interface as the xamarin.facebook.android and xamarin.facebook.IOS is not found for the UWP.

I have an alternative that opens as a browser.
[UWP](https://github.com/HoussemDellai/Facebook-Login-Xamarin-Forms)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I currently have it set up as browser based auth, I was hoping to be able to migrate all of my projects to Native login. UWP doesn't seem to have any support for it though.

So in order to make my user experience better I have to drop UWP? Nice Microsoft, excellent work.

Comment: Today, Every time I'm going to create a new project in xamarin, I think twice I already create without the UWP project, haha

Comment: actually you can make more revenue with Uwp, unless you have a great idea for android and ios. think again maybe.

Answer (score 0):

There is a nuget package called winsdkfb, you can use this package to achieve what you want. i havent tested with facebook windows 10 store application together but when it is not installed, it displays webview within your application. here there is code sample http://microsoft.github.io/winsdkfb/sample/

You can simply create a buttonrender and inject to your uwp native level. because this code you cant run on share applicaton, only in uwp native. if you need more help, please let me know.